# How to install Intrusion Detection system in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, snort

Basically i m looking for some  Intrusion Detection system....

so i find snort is one of them , soi i  need step by step configuration to install snort & some snort web-based monitoring tool 
..like " snort report "

is there any good alternative for   Intrusion Detection system ? if yes how to install them

Comment: I'm assuming 12.04 Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Snort is Network Intrusion Detection System (NIDS). Snort can sniff
>   your network and alert you based on his rule DB if there is an attack
>   on your computers network. It is an opensource system that was build
>   from tcpdump (linux sniffer tool).

[This guide can be used for installing snort.](http://nachum234.no-ip.org/security/snort/1-snort-installation-on-ubuntu-11-10-i386/)

> psad: Intrusion Detection and Log Analysis with iptables psad is a
>   collection of three lightweight system daemons (two main daemons and
>   one helper daemon) that run on Linux machines and analyze iptables log
>   messages to detect port scans and other suspicious traffic. A typical
>   deployment is to run psad on the iptables firewall where it has the
>   fastest access to log data.

If you using 12.04LTS Server, the see [How to install PSAD Intrusion Detection on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-install-psad-intrusion-detection-ubuntu-1204-lts-server)

**Sources:**
http://nachum234.no-ip.org/security/snort/1-snort-installation-on-ubuntu-11-10-i386/
http://www.cipherdyne.org/psad/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which is directly contained in the repos (so you can simply "sudo apt-get install fail2ban"). I use it for years now, and it kept a lot of hackers out of my server by blocking them. Fail2ban works by parsing log files for specified patterns (it ships with a good sample config), and then blocking the attackers IP -- e.g. if a hacker made 5 failed attempts to login via ssh (even to different accounts), you can have his IP blocked for a specified length of time (e.g. 30min). There are examples shipped for different services, just take a look at the [homepage](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for additional information.

Edit: Notifications are also possible (send a mail if something was detected).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, [a step-by-step configuration](http://wiki.aanval.com/wiki/Community%3ASnort_2.9.2.3_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu_12.04,_with_Barnyard2,_Pulledpork,_and_Aanval).

Also see [this one](http://www.symmetrixtech.com/articles/016-snortinstallguide2953.pdf), but the above worked better for me. Don't expect anything to work the first time though.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I agree @Izzy. The page is so long though, I couldn't think of a practical way to answer other than copy/pasting all 50ish pages on the URL. That would have been a formatting nightmare! :)

Comment: Well, you might at least rawly point out what it includes (maybe with some Wikipedia links to those products – I've only found [Aanval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aanval) there) *plus a few words* – I mean, *Snort* is widely known, the others I've not even heard of before), if it requires 5 years IT studies to deal with... So one knows at least what to expect and, if the page disappears one day, has some idea what to google for ;)

Comment: the link is gone :/